# Copy to clipboard function in Teams with C#

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, microsoft-teams, bot-framework-composer

I'm developing chat bot with bot framework composer. I have task "Copy table to clipboard". I used code below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ88Y.png)

I used both Systems.Windows and Systems.Windows.Forms . It's good in Emulator but it's not work in Teams. How can I fix it? please help me. Thank guys!

this error in teams:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjPjs.png)

My code with c#:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.AppendLine("<div>");
                    sb.AppendLine("<table style='width:600px; border: 1px solid; border-collapse: collapse;'>");
                    sb.AppendLine("<tr>");
                    sb.AppendLine("<td style='width:16%; border: 1px solid; font-weight: bold;'><p>Employee ID</p></td>");
                    sb.AppendLine("<td style='width:15%; border: 1px solid; font-weight: bold;'><p>Name</p></td>");
                    sb.AppendLine("<td style='width:30%; border: 1px solid; font-weight: bold;'><p>Title</p></td>");
                    sb.AppendLine("<td style='width:25%; border: 1px solid; font-weight: bold;'><p>Curriculum Code</p></td>");
                    sb.AppendLine("<td style='width:14%; border: 1px solid; font-weight: bold;'><p>Date</p></td>");
                    sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
                    var valueToCopy = JToken.Parse(token["CopyToClipBoard"].Value<string>());
                foreach(var item in valueToCopy)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine("<tr>");
                    sb.AppendLine("<td style='border: 1px solid;'><p>"+item["EmployeeID"].Value<string>()+"</p></td>");
                    sb.AppendLine("<td style='border: 1px solid;'><p>"+item["Name"].Value<string>()+"</p></td>");
                    sb.AppendLine("<td style='border: 1px solid;'><p>"+item["Title"].Value<string>()+"</p></td>");
                    sb.AppendLine("<td style='border: 1px solid;'><p>"+item["CurriculumCode"].Value<string>()+"</p></td>");
                    if (DateTime.Parse(item["Date"].Value<string>()) < DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-8))
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine("<td style='border: 1px solid;'><p style='color:red;'>"+DateTime.Parse(item["Date"].Value<string>()).ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy")+"</p></td>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine("<td style='border: 1px solid;'><p>"+DateTime.Parse(item["Date"].Value<string>()).ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy")+"</p></td>");
                    }
                    sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
                }
                    sb.AppendLine("</table>");
                    sb.AppendLine("</div>");     
                string s = sb.ToString();
                const string h = "Version:1.0\r\nStartHTML:1111111\r\nEndHTML:2222222\r\n";
                s = h.Replace( "1111111", h.Length.ToString( "0000000" ) ).Replace( "2222222", ( h.Length + s.Length ).ToString( "0000000" ) ) + s;
         
                //copy table to clipboard
                Thread thread = new Thread(() => Clipboard.SetText(s, TextDataFormat.Html));
                thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); //Set the thread to STA
                thread.Start(); 
                thread.Join();
                return;
```

I used Adaptive card to show table and button:

```
{
"schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.2",
"msteams": {
    "width": "Full"
},
"body": [
{
                        "type": "ActionSet",
                        "actions": [
                            {
                                "type": "Action.Submit",
                                "title": "Copy to clipboard"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
        "type": "Input.Text",
        "placeholder": "Placeholder text",
        "id": "CopyToClipBoard",
        "value": "[${join(foreach(collection, item, DataForCopyTest(item)), ',')}]",
        "isVisible": false
    },
    {
        "type": "ColumnSet",
        "separator": true,
        "spacing": "Padding",
        "columns": [
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "separator": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "weight": "Bolder",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "text": "Employee ID",
                        "wrap": true
                    }
                ],
                "width": "70px"
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "separator": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "weight": "Bolder",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "text": "Name",
                        "wrap": true
                    }
                ],
                "width": "80px"
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "separator": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "weight": "Bolder",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "text": "Title",
                        "wrap": true
                    }
                ],
                "width": "160px"
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "separator": true,
                "width": "150px",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "weight": "Bolder",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "text": "Curriculum Code",
                        "wrap": true
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "separator": true,
                "bleed": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "weight": "Bolder",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "text": "Due Date",
                        "wrap": true
                    }
                ],
                "width": "80px"
            }
        ],
        "bleed": true
    },
    ${join(foreach(collection, item, getColumnSet(item)), ',')}
],
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQhWO.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: As the other user mentioned, it would be great if you could update your question. From what's provided though, I suspect that the library you're using for threading and clipboard access is not supported by Teams (Unable to Reach is often a catch-all for internal application error). C# has different threading libraries for different purposes. You might want to check the Teams developer page to see what the correct pattern is.

Comment: The copy/paste etc is probably done using document.execCommand(), which can be used to trigger copy/paste and such. Check your browser to see which commands are supported.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

// on right click, copy to clipboard.
     document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('contextmenu', function( event ) {
    // prevent the normal context menu from popping up
    event.preventDefault();
    // copy current selection
    document.execCommand('copy');
});

Comment: Hi guys. I added my code. It's work good in emulator but when I deploy to Teams it's not work

Comment: Could you please share the console logs?

Comment: It's just not work and not show any errors

Answer (score 0):

**Clipboard API's currently not supported in Teams.**

Could you please raise an user voice here:
[Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)